# Cast to value type 'System.Datetime' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, null

I know this error is very common but I can't handle it with one data and `DateTime` type.

This is my LINQ:

```
var lastDate = (
    from t in context.table select t.CreatedOn
).Max();
```

What I need is get the last `DateTime` (`CreatedOn`) field getting the max of the rows.
The thing is that crash because the table is empty and I can't handle the null before the catch exception. With data it works.

***UPDATE:***
The expected result is "null" if the datetime can't be get.

With the  Pikoh commentary I could make it, but now I've the same error with a linq that have a condition (where)

```
                        lastDateWithCriteria= (
          from t in context.table
where criteria == "value"
          select t.CreatedOn).Max();
                    }
```

Comment: _"Get the last DateTime field getting the max of the rows"_ Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: What about `if (context.table.Rows.Count>0) { var lastDate...`

Comment: What do you expect it to do when there are no records?  What *should* happen?

Comment: thanks for replies. A null value. I tried with ?? DateTime.Parse or anything but LINQ doesn't get it.

Comment: What if you try `context.table.Max(t => (DateTime?)t.CreatedOn)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you can do is...

```
var lastDate = (
    from t in context.table select (DateTime?)t.CreatedOn
).Max();
```

With this cast, you tell to your code that the field CreatedOn now can be null.

You can even do, if you want, pass a default value in case the value is null...

```
var lastDate = (
        from t in context.table select (DateTime?)t.CreatedOn
    ).Max() ?? DateTime.Now;
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Take a different approach:

```
var lastRow = (
    from t in context.table 
    orderby t.CreatedOn descending
    select new { t.CreatedOn }
).FirstOrDefault();

if (lastRow != null) 
    Console.WriteLine(lastRow.CreatedOn)
```

It creates an anonymous object which only contains the date. Thus it would work with empty results.

Comment: Thanks, that's seems to be easier (sorry for my english). I didn't think about it. What I get now is... cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.DateTime?' . Googling....